# The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume C:\fs\X

Tags: hard-drive, windows-home-server

My Windows Home Server is showing disk issues.

In the Event Viewer I get the message:

**The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume C:\fs\X.**

When I log onto the Windows Home Server Console I get the message:

**An unexpected error has occurred in the Windows Home Server Storage Manager**

Most of the files on the shared folders are accessible okay, but there are some that I can see in Windows Explorer, but I cannot open them (I do have them backed up to an external disk attached to my Windows Home Server).

How can I tell which logical and physical drives the errors are on?

Thanks.

Comment: Before you do anything else, detach your external disk. It's not a backup if it's still online.

Comment: "C:\fs\X" seems quite a strange name for a volume...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue here: http://forum.wegotserved.com/index.php?/topic/10517-an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-in-the-windows-home-server-storage-manager/

Answer (score 1):

While I am no expert in WHS; have you run `chkdsk`?

Try this once per partition:

```
chkdsk <volume:>
```

If you have errors try running this:

```
chkdsk <volume:> /R
```

The `/R` will try to "fix" bad sectors, and recover the data.

You can also check your event log for `1001` events, which are related to your disk.

Comment: I usually run chkdsk at least twice, once to fix any errors that may have accumulated over a long period of time, then a second time to confirm no more sectors are going bad. Also try running a disk health utility from the HD manufacturer.